# remover pontuações do include para apontar pasta local

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include

Bem existe uma forma de remover a dupla pontuação para apontar o arquivo de uma pasta ? Eu já vi isso em alguns projetos, mais o meu da erro no include se não usar

Exemplo de como está

```
#include "../utils/bps.hpp"
```

Como quero deixar

```
#include "utils/bps.hpp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Na linha de compilação você deve passar a opção "-I..". Se for Visual Studio, usar "/I..". (Na verdade o compilador do Visual Studio também aceita opcões iniciadas por "-" mas normalmente é utilizado o "/" em lugar do "-".

Exemplo no Linux com gcc:

```
$ cc -o teste -I.. teste.cpp
```

Exemplo com Visual Studio:

```
c:\xxx> cl /I.. teste.cpp
```